# Elm Windows Installer error. ERROR: Unable to open registry key "HKCU\Environment\Path" for reading. CODE: 80070002 SOURCE: WshShell.RegRead

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I am trying to install a programming environment called Elm.

http://elm-lang.org/Install.elm

It is a functional programming language. I ran the installer on my Windows 7 machine, but when I did an error came up. I described this error in the pertinent language community but haven't received a response. Here are the two errors I received.

[image]
[image]

I am attempting to resolve this problem myself. I found a stack link that didn't really give me answers but had the error code number in it. [WshShell.RegRead fails when reading key with default value not set (WinXP only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922832/wshshell-regread-fails-when-reading-key-with-default-value-not-set-winxp-only)

I also found this article on Environmental Variables

http://best-windows.vlaurie.com/environment-variables.html

But I am not sure what to do with the information contained there. I think it is as simple as redefining one of the environment variables, but I'd like some advice if that's the right thing to do.

Currently the variable "Path" has a value "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;" and more.

Will altering this variable in someway resolve my problem? I've never done something like this before, so I am reluctant to proceed without learning what I am doing beforehand.

Comment: I recommend to include at least the error code as ascii into the text or title, better the whole error message. This makes it much easier to google; someone with the same problem will much more likely find your question (and the answer)

Comment: Brilliant. I'll do that at once. Cool

Comment: @DanielAdler Did it. Will that do? New to stackoverflow so I want to follow whatever the norm is for titles of this nature. Thanks!

Comment: I only speak for myself. The title is a bit long, but I would leave it as you did. I wouldn't have done it better. It contains everything to get an idea about the question/thread. Welcome to stackoverflow. You'll like it ;-) A more compact version is: `Elm Windows Installer error 80070002: "Unable to open registry key “HKCU\Environment\Path” for reading" Source: WshShell.RegRead`

Comment: By default, there is no user environment variable named PATH, only a system variable.  Sounds like the script doesn't handle this case.  I'd suggest you try manually editing the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` and adding a REG_EXPAND_SZ entry named PATH.  The value can just be an empty string.  That might be enough to make the installer happy.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Brilliant! It worked! Thank you señor! I love StackOverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, there is no user environment variable named PATH, only a system variable.  Sounds like the script doesn't handle this case.

As confirmed by the OP, it was sufficient to manually edi the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` to add `REG_EXPAND_SZ` entry named `PATH`. The value can just be an empty string.

I also suggest you report this as a bug.

Comment: The irony is thick on this one. The authors of a functional programming language are inserting imperative scripts into a declarative programming language.  Windows Installer supports updating environment variables using the Environment table.